# Clocking in code works for employee functions and supervisor functions individually but not when combined

Tags: python

I'm creating my own version of a program that allows employees to clock in, clock out, and view their pay checks before taxes. I also want the supervisor to have their own functions as well, such as creating schedules, calculating pay, and viewing time cards of when their employees clocked in and out. The code I have is still being worked on, but I've completed the employee functions for the most part, and now trying to do the supervisor functions. The problem is the functions work individually but not combined. Here's what I have so far. If anyone can assist, it would help a lot.

```
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now() # states date and time at point of running the file
emp_or_sup = input('Are you an employee or supervisor? ') # determines if user is an employee or the owner

# employee functions
if emp_or_sup == 'employee': # functions for when the user is an employee
    emp_id = input("Enter your employee ID: ") # allows employee to state their identification so system can find them
    print(f"Hello {emp_id}. What would you like to do?") # index to allow employees to decide what they want to do. Options including clocking in, clocking out, and viewing their paystub
    print('Options:',
      'Clock In,',
      'Clock Out,',
      'View My Pay')
    emp_task = input('I want to: ') # tasks will initiate from here

# clocking in (figure out how to save the time an employee clocked in so they can't do it more than once)
if emp_task == 'clock in': # function for when people want to clock in
    clock_in = input("Are you ready to clock in now? ")
    if clock_in == 'yes':
        print(f'Ok {emp_id}, you clocked in at {now}. Have a good day!')
    if clock_in == 'no':
        print(f'Ok {emp_id}, have a nice day!')

# clocking out (figure out how to save the time an employee clocked out so they can't do it more than once)
if emp_task == 'clock out': # function for when employees want to clock out
    clock_out = input("Are you ready to clock out now? ")
    if clock_out == 'yes':
        print(f'Ok {emp_id}, you clocked out at {now}. Have a good day!') # Ask right after if they would like to see how much they earned for the day
    if clock_out == 'no':
        print(f'Ok {emp_id}, you are still clocked in. Have a good day!')

# pay stub
if emp_task == 'view my pay': # function for when people want to see their pay
    hours = int(input('How many hours did you work? '))
    rate = int(input('How much do you earn per hour? $'))
    if hours < 40: 
        pay1 = hours * rate
        print(f'Your pay will be ${pay1} before taxes.')
    else:
        overtime_hours = hours - 40 # limit for overtime hours is dependent on the company
        new_rate = rate * 1.5 # rate for overtime pay is dependent on the company
        pay2 = float(40 * rate) + float(overtime_hours * new_rate)
        print(f'Your pay will be ${pay2} before taxes.')
        
### error begins here. The upper part works fine alone and bottom works fine 
### alone but do not work together

# supervisor functions
if emp_or_sup == 'supervisor':
    sup_pass = input('Enter supervisor password: ') # makes sure only supervisor or owner can access this
    if sup_pass == '1234': # password can be changed by owner
        print("Hello. What would you like to do?")
    else:
        print('Invalid password. Please re-enter your password.')
print('Options: '
      'Calculate Paychecks'
      'Schedule Employees'
      'View Time Cards')
sup_task = input('I want to: ')

# calculating paychecks
if sup_task == 'calculate paychecks':
    emp = input('Enter employee ID: ') # allows owner to find employees easier
    hours = int(input(f'How many hours did {emp} work? '))
    rate = int(input(f'How much does {emp} earn per hour? $'))
    if hours < 40: 
        pay1 = hours * rate
        print(f"{emp}'s pay will be ${pay1} before taxes.")
    else:
        overtime_hours = hours - 40 # limit for overtime hours is dependent on the company
        new_rate = rate * 1.5 # rate for overtime pay is dependent on the company
        pay2 = float(40 * rate) + float(overtime_hours * new_rate)
        print(f"{emp}'s pay will be ${pay2} before taxes.")
```

Comment: see [ask] a question and provide a [mcve]

Comment: You need to indent all of the employee/supervisor code under the 'initial' `emp_or_sup` tests - otherwise all that code will run for both cases. Ultimately this should probably be done with function definitions for clarity and safety.

Answer (score 1):

The error happens because `emp_task` is only defined when `emp_or_sup == 'employee'`. If that is not the case, it is being evaluated before it is initialized, causing an error.

Either define that variable beforehand, or only check it in the case that `emp_or_sup == 'employee'`